# Alternative ways to dynamically create li elements

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

Using JavaScript, I need to dynamically create a list like this:

```
<ul id="list">
<li>2015</li>
<li>2016</li>
<li>2017</li>
<li>2018</li>
<li>2019</li>
<li>2020</li>
</ul>
```

The "classic solution" (as far as I know) is:

```
for (var i = 2015; i <= 2020; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = i;
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

It works perfectly.

But I would like to find alternative, better - in terms of performance - solutions, if there are (I want to learn something more).

So I tried:

```js
for (var i = 2015; i <= 2020; i++) {
  var el = "<li>" + i + "</li>";
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', el);
  console.log(el);
  el += el;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

AND

```js
for (var i = 2015; i <= 2020; i++) {
  var el = "<li>" + i + "</li>";
  list.innerHTML += el;
  console.log(el);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

But in both cases this is the result:

- in the DOM:

```
<ul id="list">
<li>2015</li>
<li></li>
<li>2016</li>
<li></li>
<li>2017</li>
<li></li>
<li>2018</li>
<li></li>
<li>2019</li>
<li></li>
<li>2020</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

- while in the console:

```
<li>2015<li>
<li>2016<li>
<li>2017<li>
<li>2018<li>
<li>2019<li>
<li>2020<li>
```

Why those empty nodes (`<li></li>`)? And why in the DOM only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both you added `"<li>" + i + "<li>"` instead of `"<li>" + i + "</li>"`
Missing `slash` small thing, but **user agents** are prepared to fix missing closing... and your code appeared with doubled `li`